# Symfony 2.1.13 assets do not load only for some users

Tags: symfony

Parts of the users the application written in Symfony 2.1.13 opens very slowly.
I found a problem. For these users, which opens up much slower for some reason, the browser tries to download all css / js files and can not do this (403):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:10 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:22 +0100] "GET /css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:27 +0100] "GET /css/lib/chosen.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:33 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:39 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.structure.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:45 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:51 +0100] "GET /css/prod/prod_css.css HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:40:57 +0100] "GET /js/lib/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:04 +0100] "GET /js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:10 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:16 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.proto.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:22 +0100] "GET /js/lib/clipboard.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:28 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:34 +0100] "GET /js/lib/simplemodal.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:40 +0100] "GET /js/prod/prod_js.js HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:46 +0100] "GET /images/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:46 +0100] "GET /images/phone2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_1 [28/Feb/2019:12:41:46 +0100] "GET /images/scrollup.png HTTP/1.1" 304 (...)
```

For those users who works quickly gets what it should or minimized version:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_2 [28/Feb/2019:12:42:32 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_2 [28/Feb/2019:12:42:32 +0100] "GET /css/prod/prod_css.css HTTP/1.1" 200 (...)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user_2 [28/Feb/2019:12:42:33 +0100] "GET /js/prod/prod_js.js HTTP/1.1" 200 (...)
```

I would like to point out that I have ruled out the browser, system, etc, because if on the same computer and browser, it logs in (by running as ...) two users it will be the same (what was slow will be slow and what working normally will work normally)

Does anyone have any idea why this is so?

**EDIT**

It fixed itself for two days and again the problem came back. The network profiler shows: [ibb.co/Y7V3HHL](http://ibb.co/Y7V3HHL) The same computer, but another user logged into the browser (via the "Run as a different user" option): [ibb.co/QXhsfZP](http://ibb.co/QXhsfZP)

*ssl_access_log* for this user:

```
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:17 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 72983 "-" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:28 +0100] "GET /css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 200 930 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:34 +0100] "GET /css/lib/chosen.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13478 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:39 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 31030 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - - [04/Mar/2019:08:15:48 +0100] "-" 408 - "-" "-" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:45 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.structure.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 15548 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:51 +0100] "GET /css/lib/jquery-ui.theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13889 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:15:57 +0100] "GET /css/prod/xxx.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18022 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:03 +0100] "GET /js/lib/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93033 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:09 +0100] "GET /js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 253668 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:15 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 44133 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:21 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.proto.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 28322 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:27 +0100] "GET /js/lib/clipboard.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10000 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:33 +0100] "GET /js/lib/chosen.jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:39 +0100] "GET /js/lib/simplemodal.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9776 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:45 +0100] "GET /js/prod/xxx.js HTTP/1.1" 200 43341 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:51 +0100] "GET /images/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 3208 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:52 +0100] "GET /images/scrollup.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1812 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:52 +0100] "GET /images/phone2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 431 "https://web_name.pl/" (...) 
my_ip - user_3 [04/Mar/2019:08:16:57 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1580 "-"  (...)
```

Comment: The logs you show say the requests for loading the assets returns status code 304. This is a status code used with caching, when the content has not changed. All it should do is signify the user that their cached content (in the browser cache) is still fresh and can be used, meaning the response itself does not contain data, but it is supposed to be in the browser cache. Are you sure this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Have you try to [profile](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem, but the time between consecutive messages looks like it would try to download more files and probably everything is slow through timeout.

Comment: It fixed itself for two days and again the problem came back. The network profiler shows: 
https://ibb.co/Y7V3HHL
The same computer, but another user logged into the browser (via the "Run as a different user" option):
https://ibb.co/QXhsfZP